# WWS server not responding over a network

Tags: c++, wwsapi

I have been testing WCF and WWS services, both my own and the [SortService by Mykolad Dudar](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nikolad/archive/2009/03/03/demo-of-wwsapi-from-mvp-summit.aspx).

First the WCF version is created, and then wsutil is used for the WWS version. 
Both the WCF and WWS services are working fine if the server and client run on the same machine. However, the WWS server is not responding if the server and client are on different machines. The WCF version works fine.

The binding is wshttp and security is set to ’None’. No firewalls or anti virus programs running.

This is the error message I get on the client calling the WWS:

Error: There was no endpoint listening at http://10.100.81.218:8080/SortService
that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or S
OAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

The InnerException is empty.

I’m sure I’m missing something, can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working. In case anyone else encounters the same problem, here is how:

Turns out that using ‘localhost’ in the web service url was the problem (on the server). Using the machine IP address instead, solved the problem.

Using ‘localhost’ for the WCF service worked fine, so there is a difference between WCF and WWS on this point.